# to integrate fabric.js rectangle in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks, react-component

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
const Canvas = () => {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState('');  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);  
  
  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
    })
  ); 
  const addRect = canvi => {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      height: 280,
      width: 200,
      fill: 'yellow'
    });
    canvi.add(rect);
    canvi.renderAll();
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addRect(canvas)}></button>
     <br/><br/>
     <canvas id="canvas" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Canvas;
```

I want to display the rectangle without using the button and also to display its state on the browser
the onload event is also not working in the react I also tried to use the other alternative of onload but it's of no help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also working on this if you want to add rect without button click you can add it into the useEffect.

```
const fuctionName = ()=>{

useEffect(() => {



  return () => {

 const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-main');


 const rect = new fabric.Rect({

     height: 280,

      width: 200,

      fill: 'yellow',

    });

 canvas.add(rect);

  }
}, [])

 return (
    <>
      <canvas


        style={{ border: 'solid 1px #555' }}


        id="canvas-main"


        width="600px"


        height="600px"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```